# Error logging in at FormLogin, Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

I get an error like this , where when I fill in the username and password, about an error found like this, I'm confused, which part is wrong.

```
Additional information: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'admin‘and tipe='Admin‘' at line 1
```

And this my full code

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Call koneksi()
        Dim sql, username, password, tipe As String
        username = txtLogin.Text
        password = txtPassword.Text
        tipe = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        sql = “select * from tbl_login where user='” + username + “‘and pass='” + password + “‘and tipe='” + tipe + “‘”
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(sql, conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If rd.HasRows = True And ComboBox1.SelectedItem = “Admin” Then
            FormMenuUtama.Show()
            Me.btnLogin.Enabled = False
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf rd.HasRows = True And ComboBox1.SelectedItem = “Operator” Then
            FormMenuUtama.Show()
            Me.btnLogin.Enabled = False
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(“Data Yang Anda Masukkan Salah”, “Konfirmasi”, MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Me.Show()
            Me.btnLogin.Enabled = True
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

how to fix it ? Thank you :)

Comment: Check the quote char before the pass and user variables. Notice how it is not the same char used after the variables. Said that look as soon as possible to what is Sql Injection. Your code is really a security problem

Comment: You can see that the exception is pointing you at `user='” + username + “‘and pass='”`. There's no space between the `username` value and the following `and`. As already mentioned, use Parameters to compose your queries. Possibly, use the standard double quotes: `"`, so the same symbol defines a string boundaries. (... *more stuff* ...)